# Muscial notation on the iPhone. Any suggestions for example code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notation

I'm writing an iPhone app where I'd like to display some simple musical notation (just a chord or two).

This question is a call for suggestions on the quickest way to go about it. For instance:

1. Is there any iphone OR objective-C libraries for doing this that I'm missing?
2. Are there any examples of open-source objective-C software in the wild I could look at? It wouldn't have to be iPhone specific.
3. If there isn't any objective-C code to do this, anyone know of any musicial-notation rendering software in other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, MusicKit is an audio tool, not a symbolic tool like you need.

I don't know of any open-source Objective-C music notation programs. However, the recently-released [Zong! Viewer](http://www.xenoage.com/zongviewer.html) is an open-source (GPL) Java program. You can't run Java on the iPhone, of course, but it might give you some ideas for structuring your software. [MuseScore](http://www.musescore.org/) is an open source music notation editor that might provide more ideas.

So far the only iPhone music notation application I know is [pocketscore](http://www.electricears.com/prod_tpl2.php?id=67). It has the great idea of exporting MusicXML files via e-mail so you can work on your music later with a more full-featured program than you can write on an iPhone.

There might be other open source programs you can check out on the [MusicXML software list](http://www.makemusic.com/musicxml/community/software). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is an objective-c music analysis framework which may have what you need:

[musickit](http://www.musickit.org/)

Comment: This a cool library that I hadn't seen. Thanks. However I really am looking for the visual representation of music whereas that library seems more audio based