# Best API for iOS Music Notation and Playback

Tags: iphone, audio, ios

I'm constructing an application that allows you to compose and play back your compositions for iOS.  I looked into CoreMIDI (new to 4.2), but I'm not looking to interface with any keyboards or other MIDI hardware and think there may be a simpler way.  Does anyone else have any suggestions on the best API to use for this type of task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for something similar. I found this app (PocketScore), mentioned in this thread: [Muscial notation on the iPhone. Any suggestions for example code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810207/muscial-notation-on-the-iphone-any-suggestions-for-example-code). However I couldn't find an API / Framework.

Is something like PocketScore that you are looking for? That is, "visual representation of music"?